# KeyError / Unregistered Task - Celery Worker/RabbitMQ/Redis/FastAPI

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, task

For whatever reason Celery is not picking up the task to be registered.

```
celery_worker_1  | The delivery info for this task is:
celery_worker_1  | {'consumer_tag': 'None4', 'delivery_tag': 5, 'redelivered': False, 'exchange': '', 'routing_key': 'celery'}
celery_worker_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
celery_worker_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 591, in on_task_received
celery_worker_1  |     strategy = strategies[type_]
celery_worker_1  | KeyError: 'get_option'
```

Project Structure

```
/server
  /db
  /router
  /worker
    celery_app.py
    celery_worker.py
  app.py
```

celery_app.py

```py
...
celery_app = Celery(
    "worker",
    backend=os.getenv("CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND", "redis://redis:6000/0"),
    broker=os.getenv("CELERY_BROKER_URL", "amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672//"),
    include=['worker.celery_worker']
)

celery_app.autodiscover_tasks()
...
```

celery_worker.py

```py
from worker.celery_app import celery_app
...
@celery_app.task(bind=True, name="get_option")
def get_option(self, expiration: str, option_type: str, symbol: str):
...
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
...
celery_worker:
    build: server/worker
    command: celery -A celery worker -l debug
    volumes:
      - ./worker:/tmp/worker
    environment:
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672//
      - CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://@redis:6000/0
    depends_on:
      - db
      - rabbitmq
      - redis
...
```

Comment: How are you starting your Celery worker?

Comment: @M.O.Hey I added the excerpt from the docker-compose to show how it is starting.